# How to loop an input from user?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, input

How can I begin a loop where the given input;

```
raffle_ticket = input("Enter Participant Here: ")
```

repeated until I get maximum 20 participant inputs from user, then break the input loop when I get 20 participants?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for loop and store the input from user into a list:

```
raffle_ticket = []

for i in range(0,20):
    raffle_ticket.append(input("Enter Participant Here: ")) 
    
print(raffle_ticket)
```

Comment: Thank you!  Worked like a charm.  This algorithm  allowed me to create a list, which then I was able to randomize the entire list and select one winner afterwards (small little project I am doing for a friend and his jewelry business).

Comment: Good job. Keep it up!